# Re-populating / Editing HTML form inputs using MySQL Data

Tags: php, html, mysql

Being new to PHP and SQL, I have build a simple HTML form with 20 inputs, allowing users to enter specific data through input type=text or file. I have  built a mysql database where this user data is inserted / saved. All is working, this is a major accomplishment for me.

I'm asking for help on this next step, I think this step would be called “edit”?

This step would allow users to recall the mysql data they entered, at a later time, to edit and save. Would like to have this recalled data injected directly into the original HTML form. Now, it seems necessary to have a method, (possibly a HTML form  ”id “input), that calls from the data base, the specific record (including all 20 data inputs) that is associated with this user. Am I thinking correctly?

I'm asking for help / direction with simple yet detailed approach to solve this step. Note, my few attempts at this “edit” step, using some examples, have failed. I do not have a firm grasp of this PHP, yet have strong desire to become proficient.

This is a model, stripped down version of my current working code. I eliminated the `$connection = mysql_connect.`

This is the PHP I built, working great!

```
<?php
require('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['first_name'])){

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];

    $favorite_color = $_POST['favorite_color'];

    $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $query = "INSERT into `form_data` (first_name, favorite_color, trn_date) VALUES ('$first_name', '$favorite_color', '$trn_date')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result){
        echo "<div class='form'><h1>First Name & Favorite Color POST to db was successfull.</h1>
        <br/><h3>Click here to return <a href='https://jakursmu.com/tapcon_builder/tb_form_data_1.1.php'>TapCon Builder</a></h3>
        </div>";

    }
}else{
```

?>

This is the HTML user form, works great with the PHP script:

```
<div class="form">
    <h1>First Name & Favorite Color "POST" to db Test</h1>
    <form target="_blank" name="registration" action=" " method="post">
        <p> First Name<input name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" /> </p>
        <p> Favorite Color <input name="favorite_color" type="text" placeholder="Favorite Color" /> </p>
        <p> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit / Update to db" /></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Suppose the user queries the database using their “first_name”, when this “edit” step is completed, the final result will render / inject the users “first_name” and “favorite_color” back into the original HTML form. Does this make sense?

The database I created for this help post, looks like this:

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvr8O.jpg)

When a user wishes to edit their data, they can enter their "first_name", in a form text input, (im assuming?) where their "first_name" will be found in the data base. The ouutput result of this database query will be injected into the original form, ready for any user edit.

```
User Edit for:  Results (in origingal form):
Jack            Jack    Black
Jeff            Jeff    Green
Randall         Randall Red
So on.........
```

I hope this explanation makes sense where any experienced help or direction is offered.

Thanks for viewing!

Answer (score 0):

just for practice purposes, but can look into prepared statements at you liesure time.

first create ur php file

```
<form method="post" action="edit.php">
  <?php

  //in ur php tag. select items from the row based on an id you've passed on to the page

  $sql = "select * from 'form_data' where blah = '$blah'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

  if($result){

     $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
     if($count > 0) {

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            $name = $row['firstname'];
            $lname = $row['lastname'];

            //you can now echo ur input fields with the values set in
            echo'

                 <input type="text" value="'.$name.'" >
                   ';//that how you set the values


         }

     }


 }

  ?>
```

```
</form>
```

Finally you can run and update statement on submit of this you dynamically generated form input.

Also please switch to mysqli or pdo, alot better that the deprecated mysql.
look into prepared statements too. Hope this nifty example guides you down the right path...

Comment: This won't work, nor does it directly answer OP's question. Offering an answer using `mysqli_` when OP is using standard `mysql_` does not help the cause. Offer the answer using OP's code, then offer an additional method of using `mysqli_` if you feel like it. Plus, wrapping the table name in the query with single-quotes `'form_data'` will throw an error. Backticks or nothing at all.

Comment: @Mueyiwa - Thank you for your direction. Being inexperienced in .php, I’m having difficulty following your suggestion. A large misunderstand I have on this “edit” step, is the method that is required directing the users search for their name in the db. Im assuming a form input with submit must be necessary? With that said, I will work on your suggestion in hopes of finding my way. Any other clear detailed direction is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: @Marcus - Thank you for viewing my help needed post. Would there be a possibility where you may be able to direct me with any clear details on my request? I will work on Mueyiwa’s suggestion to solve this re-populate / edit step of my project. I will do the same should you direct me. Thank You.